# Persist overlay line over map view in iOS6

Tags: iphone, path, mkmapview

I have map view over which i like to draw line using overlay method, i added two location latitude and longitude to draw line between them when i pressed button, but when i pressed second time new paire of coordinates i provide and new line over map appers but previous overlay path got vanished, but i need previou path on the same map also

here is my code .

```
- (IBAction)refreshMapMethod:(id)sender

{


 int kk=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"ham"];




    if (kk==1)
    {
         CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateArray[2];
        coordinateArray[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(12.915181,+77.626055);
        coordinateArray[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(12.892156, +77.582188);
        self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinateArray count:2];
        [self.myMapView setVisibleMapRect:[self.routeLine boundingMapRect]];

        [self.myMapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:2 forKey:@"ham" ];


    }


    if (kk==2)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateArray[2];
        coordinateArray[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(12.892156,+77.426055);
        coordinateArray[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(12.892156, +77.582188);
        self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinateArray count:2];
        [self.myMapView setVisibleMapRect:[self.routeLine boundingMapRect]];

        [self.myMapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:3 forKey:@"ham" ];


    }
    if (kk==3)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateArray[2];
        coordinateArray[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(12.892156, +77.382188);
        coordinateArray[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(12.892156, +77.282188);
        self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinateArray count:2];
        [self.myMapView setVisibleMapRect:[self.routeLine boundingMapRect]];

        [self.myMapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:3 forKey:@"ham" ];


    }



    CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
    zoomLocation.latitude= 12.915181;
    zoomLocation.longitude=77.626055;

    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion=MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 3*METERS_PER_MILE, 3*METERS_PER_MILE);

    [self.myMapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];


 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:2 forKey:@"change" ];


}
```

calling overlay method ..

```
-(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay


{

    if(overlay == self.routeLine)
    {
        if(nil == self.routeLineView)
        {
          self.routeLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine];



            self.routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
            self.routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
            self.routeLineView.lineWidth = 5;

        }

        return self.routeLineView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

please provide me the solution in tye same way or the other any alternate way .

than you .

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are only allowing the `viewForOverlay` function to return the view for `self.routeline` and you only have one of those. Every other call to `viewForOverlay` will return nil and therefore not be drawn. What you need to do is draw all the overlays.

```
-(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKPolylineView* routeLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:(MKPolyLine)overlay];
    routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
    routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    routeLineView.lineWidth = 5;

    return routeLineView;
}
```

You'll probably need to do some more stuff like checking the overlay actually is a polyline first, but this should be enough to get you going.